# Tinymce and HTML tags - Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, tinymce-rails

I am working on Ruby on Rails. TinyMCE converts my HTML tags like:

```
<span>Hi</span>
```

to:

```
"&lt;span&gt;Hi&lt;/span&gt;"
```

config/tinymce.yml

```
menubar: false
toolbar:
  - bold italic underline | undo redo
plugins:
- table
  - image
  - link
forced_root_block: ""
force_br_newlines : true
force_p_newlines : false
```

I have tried setting encoding: false in config/tinymce.yml but it isn't working.

I don't know what setting to change. I read here: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#encoding
that encoding is disabled by default but still it is encoding for me.

Can anyone point the problem!

Comment: I've not used TinyMCE; in CKEditor you set all the settings in the `ckeditor/init.js` file. The docs you recommended seem to be suggesting a similar setup - do you have a `/init.js` file or equivalent?

Comment: Whatever is set in config/tinymce.yml initializes the editor. Can also do it through a js file.

Comment: Did you restart your server when you added the `encoding: false` tag to the `yml`?

Comment: Yup. Didn't do anything different

Comment: Interesting. Do you have a github repo I could look at?